# Creating a cookie from a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I want to practice creating cookies and I have found a lot of samples around the internet. I tried to implement the code on my own, but when I test it, nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
        }

            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            function cookieText() {
                var username = document.getElementByID("sometext").value;
                    setCookie("username", user, 30);
            }

            function showCookie() {
                var user=getCookie("username");
                    alert("Hello " + user);
            }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="someText"></input>
        <input type="button" value="create cookie!" onClick="cookieText();"></input>
        <input type="button" value="show the cookie!" onClick = "showCookie();"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I press `show the cookie!` button (I have already entered something on the textfield and clikced the `create cookie!` button) nothing happens. The JavaScript alert is not even showing. I wonder where the code went wrong.

Comment: Lots of issues - it's getElementById not ByID, you haven't defined 'user' anywhere, 'sometext' should be 'someText' etc. Please check the console tools when debugging

Comment: @daniel thank you for pointing those out. I'll redo the whole thing.

Comment: No worries, maybe a useful link (getting to know them well will save you so much time): https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @daniel thank you so much for the tip :) have a nice day